# Mysql query variable inside function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

```
<?php 

function get_msg($c_id_fk) {

    $messages = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM conversation_reply WHERE c_id_fk = $c_id_fk");

    return $messages;

}

?>
```

How do I query a mysql database using a variable within a function. I'm using  $sql = new MySQLi($host, $username, $password, $database); to connect my database but and it is definitely connected because I can query it without using functions.

```
<?php $messages = get_msg(1);
                    foreach ( $messages as $message ) {
            ?>

            <!-- Individual Message -->
            <div class="bubble <?php 
                    if ( $message['user_id_fk'] == $uid ) { 
                        echo "from-me";
                    }
                    else { 
                        echo "from-them";
                    }?>">

                <?php echo $message['c_id_fk'];?><?php echo $message['user_id_fk'];?><?php echo $message['reply'];?>
            </div>

            <!-- End Individual Message -->
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Research [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$sql` does not exist in the function's scope.  You need to pass `$sql` to the function, avoid using globals.  Read into **[variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)**.

```
function get_msg($sql, $c_id_fk) {

    // Protect against injections
    $c_id_fk = (int) $c_id_fk;

    $messages = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM conversation_reply WHERE c_id_fk = $c_id_fk");

    return $messages;

}

get_msg($sql, 1);
```

Comment: or can be used database class as [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), and grab it, where ever it needs like `$db = DBSource::getInstance();`